# How to display chats with the newest message foccused

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

i am developing a web app in laravel. It has got to a point where when the messages are many, I have to scroll down to see the newest message.
[this is how the chats display onload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baZVw.png)

I would like to focus on the newest message.
[This way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnd8w.png)

am having this :

// 
$conversations=Conversation::where('s_id',auth()->user()->id)
`enter code here`->orWhere('r_id',auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('updated_at','desc')->get();

Comment: This seems like you just need to sort your thread with user and timestamp, however, if it's more than that, we will need enough of the related code to be able replicate the problem. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you asked a similar question just moments ago. The answer was posted there as well.

You need to sort your messages via a timestamp, and all chat implementations should have a timestamp.

It's hard to go into further detail without knowing your storage engine, database engine, coding implementations etc.